# How to redirect to a bookmark URL in crossrider?

Tags: javascript, crossrider

In crossrider, I've a function in the background-codes as

```
function buttonClick() {
  alert(2);
  // simulates similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
  var url = "http://12bubbles.com";    
  window.location.replace(url);
}
```

After installing the extension, when buttonClicked() is called, the `alert()` did pop up but the redirect doesn't work. Is something wrong with my codes??

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it in a few days please. That would really help other users. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured out. If anyone is facing the same problem, I simple had to use their own API

```
function buttonClick() {
      alert(2);
      // simulates similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
      var url = "http://12bubbles.com";    
      appAPI.openURL(url, "current");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.href = url;`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = url;
```

is the proper syntax

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe it's something 'Crossrider' specific then.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cross-rider but I'm surprised that this wouldn't work. Maybe try just `window.location = url`?

Comment: I tried that too. Both works when I tried in localhost but I can't get it working with Crossrider. Anyway, thanks for helping me out!!